# Environment variables set up in Windows for pyspark

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark, environment-variables

I have Spark installed in my laptop. And I am able to execute `spark-shell` command and open the scala shell as shown below:

```sh
C:\Spark1_6\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\bin>spark-shell
scala>
```

But when I am trying to execute `pyspark` command:

```sh
C:\Spark1_6\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\bin>pyspark
```

I am getting the below error message:

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I did set up the environment User 'Path' variable manually.
By appending with

> ";C:\Python27"

I rebooted the laptop and still get the same error.
Can anyone please help me how to fix this ? Am I not correctly updating the environment variable?

Versions: Spark: 1.6.2 Windows: 8.1

Comment: What happens when you run command "python" in shell?

Comment: same error Iam getting if i enter 'python' command as well.

Comment: Are you sure that you have properly set the path variable? Check your installation path and see whether it is the same as the path given.

Comment: your python is not installed correctly

Comment: I download python from https://www.python.org/downloads/.

Comment: When I installed Python 2.7 version I thought it is installed in Python27 folder in my C drive, but when I see Python27 is not existing at all. My bad.

Comment: I uninstalled it. And installing the 3.6 version 'python-3.6.1-amd64.exe' now.

Comment: Hey I installed 3.6 version of Python and the location of `.exe` file is `"C:\Python"`. So I have updated the User variable 'Path' by appending `";C:\Python"`. After that I restarted the laptop and then I still see the same error.

Comment: Am I missing anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Spark documentation is available. Don't be afraid, read it.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/configuration.html#environment-variables

> Certain Spark settings can be configured through environment variables, which are read from ... `conf\spark-env.cmd` on Windows
>  
>   ...
>   **`PYSPARK_PYTHON`**   Python binary executable to use for
>   PySpark in both driver and workers (default is `python2.7` if available, otherwise `python`).
>   **`PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`**   Python binary executable to use
>   for PySpark in driver only (default is PYSPARK_PYTHON).

Try something like this:

```
set PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Python27\bin\python.exe
pyspark
```

Comment: Hi Samson, I have given this command like `set PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Python\python-3.6.1-amd64.exe` because the `.exe` file is in 'C:Python' folder. And after that I entered `pyspark` then I get a new window asking for modify/repair/uninstall python.

Comment: Looks like I have downloaded `python-3.6.1-amd64.exe` which is not the correct one. I should download `Windows x86-64 MSI installer`. So I did installed it. Now I could see the folder Python27 in which I could see all files and folders related to Python. Now I tried to set the path as `set PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Python27\bin\python.exe`

Comment: I entered the command `pyspark` but getting the error message `The system cannot find the path specified.` Can any one please let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: I just gave the `PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Python27\python.exe` because my python.exe file is not in bin folder, so I removed it and set the path. After that `pyspark` command worked and could open the pyspark shell. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when the path to the Python executable contains spaces. That confuses pyspark on Windows.

Make sure python.exe is in the PATH, and then simply declare `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python.exe` and that should make it work.